# Django generating the form tags instead of hardcoding them

Tags: python, django

I am having issues with having to hardcode the   tags into the templates in Django. The reason I have issues is that I need to have the forms generated dynamically based on a framework I am working on.

That framework (written in Python) has a webinterface (hence Django) that requires forms for each module in the framework, depending on the data that needs to be submitted to that module.

So I am trying to get the form information (which fields, type of fields, labels etc.) from the module, which I currently am trying like so:

```
#framework/module.py
    def form():
        forms = '"upload": {"filename": "file","directory": "text"}'
    return forms
```

The reason it is constructed like that, at this moment, is because I try to pass this information to the forms.py from Django so it can then be translated into what Django needs to create the output for the template.

Now I have tried a couple of ways on how to get it onto the template. The only problem is, that I have to create the form tags hardcoded into the template. I am trying to figure out how to get the form tags also generated dynamically based on the information supplied by the module. Because there could be modules that require multiple forms on the same page.

So in short, I am trying to do this:

```
{% for f in forms %}
    {{f}}
{% endfor %}
```

Instead of this:

```
<form name="upload" action="foo" method="POST">
    {{form}}
</form>
```

Is this possible in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render your form fields manually in django, [here is how](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT: I didn't get the question properly**

You could have your form tag attributes in a dictionary and iterate through your forms in a structure like this:

Python:

```
forms = {
    form_object: {"name": "upload", "action": "foo", "method": "POST"}
}
```

Template:

```
{% for form, tag_attributes in forms.items %}
    <form name="{{tag_attributes.name}}" action="{{tag_attributes.action}}" action="{{tag_attributes.method}}">
        Do stuff with your {{form}}
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have found that as well, but how do I set the <form> tags dynamically with each form with the name attribute set to a certain value based on the module loaded? Without hard coding the <form> tags.

Comment: Thanks, I have thought of that as well, but couldn't figure out how to combine the form tag object with the form fields. Do you have an idea on that? Because I tried adding the form fields in the way Django works with them (forms.CharField(etc.)) to a dictionary, but it won't take those in that way. (maybe I am doing it wrong, but this is the error I got when trying that:

    TypeError: Can't convert 'CharField' object to str implicitly

Comment: I was assuming you already had your form object, you can define your form as you want and once you have it in your template, you can combine with the first part of the answer: `{% for field in form %}`. You don't need to "combine" them, just define your tag attribute in a separate dictionary and use another dictionary with key=form_object and value=tag_dict

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thank you so much! I am still learning python and Django, so sometimes the most easy approach eludes me :)